# [UIBarButtonItem superview]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using the code for  segue:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(UIButton *)sender
{
    menuVC *menuview = [segue destinationViewController];
    CGPoint centerOfButton = [sender.superview convertPoint:sender.center toView:nil];

    [self.circularTransitionHandler transitionWithDestinationViewController:menuview initialTransitionPoint:centerOfButton];
}
```

App crashed:

> **terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIBarButtonItem superview]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffb74293b10**'

Comment: add exception breakpoint and check line of crash

Comment: its 5th line          [self.circularTransitionHandler transitionWithDestinationViewController:menuview initialTransitionPoint:centerOfButton];

Comment: whats your menuView and centerOfbutton values

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to access your tapped button? So when you're trying to get your buttons superview, app does crashing. Unfortunately, `UIBarButtonItem` not having `superview` property. You need to  use `.view` of your `UIBarButtonItem`.

Please update your code like this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    menuVC *menuview = [segue destinationViewController];
    UIBarButtonItem *item = (UIBarButtonItem *)sender;
    UIView *view = [item valueForKey:@"view"];
    CGPoint centerOfButton = [view convertPoint:view.center toView:nil];    
    [self.circularTransitionHandler transitionWithDestinationViewController:menuview initialTransitionPoint:centerOfButton];
}
```

See the argument type I have changed.

Comment: not working , crashed, it says:  [UIBarButtonItem center]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fcfbb240dd0'

Answer (score 1):

```
`UIBarButtonItem` does not extend `UIView` thus it has no frame property. 
We can get center point of button like this:


    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
    {
        menuVC *menuview = [segue destinationViewController];
        UIView *barView = [sender valueForKey:@"view"];
        if (barView) {
        CGRect buttonFrame = [barView convertPoint: barView.bounds toView:self.view];   

        CGPoint centerOfButton = CGPointMake(buttonFrame.origin.x + buttonFrame.size.width/2,
                                           buttonFrame.origin.y + buttonFrame.size.height/2);

        [self.circularTransitionHandler transitionWithDestinationViewController:menuview 
                                                      initialTransitionPoint:centerOfButton];
         }
    }
```

Comment: How do you get `.view` property of `UIBarButtonItem`?

Comment: UIBarButtonItem itself have the view property and I am using UIBarButtonItem with method directly.

Comment: You can use UIView *view = [sender valueForKey:@"view"];   valueForKey property to get it I also updated my answer please check.